# Is there a way not to use variables in the cypress spec to iterate through?

Tags: javascript, variables, automated-tests, cypress

I am presented with a bit of a challenge that I can't seem to figure out how to do. Hoping the community is able to point out some solutions.

I have a Cypress Spec file where we declare a number of variables to iterate through and click, to test if the page exists and loads, however I feel that this will be a nightmare to maintain within the spec file, as the chances of the amount of tabs can and will change over time.

I had 2 possible solutions in mind:

1. use a fixture to list the tabs. Pro: all the tabs to test are in a single place and easy to change, but might not be much better then using the variables in the spec
2. using cy.intercept to grab the json file that is generated and then use that to list the tabs and test them. This would, in my opinion, would result in zero maintenance as when the tabs change it will be already reflected in the JSON. this would make the test a lot more robust and resilient to changes
   below is the original code that runs and works fine

```html
describe("Analytics", () => {
  beforeEach("Login", () => {
    cy.session("Save Session", () => {
      cy.login();
      cy.url().should("contain", "/home");
      cy.get(".CookiesPopup > button").contains("OK").click();
      cy.wait(1000);
    });
  });

  // after(() => {
  //     cy.logout()
  // });

  context("Tabs", () => {
    it("Verify Tabs", () => {
      var header = [
        "Hot Topics",
        "Demand Space",
        "Category Development",
        "Brands",
        "A. Column",
        "B. Stacked",
        "C. Pie Chart",
        "D. Heatmaps",
        "E. Line Charts",
        "F. Text Widget",
        "G. Analytics & Images",
        "H. Table",
        "I. Maps",
        "J. Interactivity",
      ];
      cy.visit("/data");
      cy.get("li.level-0").each(($li, i) => {
        cy.wrap($li).should("be.visible").and("contain", header[i]).click();
        cy.wait(1000);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Is that the extent of the tab list? Looks manageable to me, why complicate it with more code?

Comment: @sariget, It's not "complicating". I would do the 2nd option no doubt. Even less code.